# Postgis: WGS84 Lat Lon Point to Gauss-Kruger 3

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

How do I convert a WGS84 lat lon point in PostGIS to [Guass Kruger 3 (31467)](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31467)?

Somehow, I do not seem to get it right. I tried the usual way for converting projections:

```
st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(50, 8), 2346), 31467)
```

However, this gives an out of bounds error. I assume PostGIS expects the values to be Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: EPSG::2346 is also a Gauss-Kruger projection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe just a typo? WGS84 is 4326.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the answer is so simple yet hard to find out... That is probably a very old typo going througout quite a lot of my queries...